# jquery post going in loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I've this code which I'm using to post a message on 'Enter' key press, but it's going on loop and instead of posting one message it's posting it multiple times randomly.

This is the function I'm calling in on `<input id='txtsendmsg" + i + "' placeholder=\"Write a comment...\" onkeypress='PostMessage(event,"+i+");'  class='msgtxt'></input>` any help would be appreciated.

```
function PostMessage(event,key) {
    $('#txtsendmsg'+key).on("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var msgid = $(this).siblings('.msgid').val();
            var msgtxt = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "student_post_login.aspx/funPostMessage",
                data: 'postd=' + "Y" + '&msgid=' + msgid + '&msgtxt=' + msgtxt,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        displayData();
                    }

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("Faliure:");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it will help but you can try async:false in your ajax code and also in success function, you should try return false. I know you are using e.preventDefault(), but still. Also from the PostMessage itself, you should return false;

Comment: Can you post your displayData() code? May be the culprit is in there?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is because you are attaching an event handler every time you hit the a key in the input field. Press a key twice and you get two requests sent, three times; three and so on.

Try assigning the handler using jQuery only instead of the `onclick` attribute:

```
<input id='txtsendmsg" + i + "' placeholder=\"Write a comment...\" class='msgtxt' />
```

```js
$('.msgtxt').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var msgid = $el.siblings('.msgid').val();
        var msgtxt = $el.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "student_post_login.aspx/funPostMessage",
            data: 'postd=' + "Y" + '&msgid=' + msgid + '&msgtxt=' + msgtxt,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    displayData();
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Faliure:");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe he is attaching the handler every time he presses a key, not only `enter`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici You are correct indeed, sir. That's even worse then :)

Comment: hey thx for that, but the code is going on loop on just one enter and i tried that its working fine if i do with php but not in aspx any other suggestions?